# AngularJS read, create, edit, delete functions in one controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, crud

I have such a controller:

```
myCtrls.controller( 'profile' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$timeout' , function( $scope , $http, $timeout ){

$scope.saveChangesMotivation = function ( motivation ) {

    $http.post( 'api/admin/motivation/updateMotivation/', {
        motivation : motivation
    } ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.msg = true;

        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.msg = false;
        }, 1500);
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Bład komunikacji z API' );
    });

};

$scope.deleteMotivation = function ( motivation , $index ) {

    if( !confirm( 'Czy na pewno chcesz usunac ten motivation?' ) )
        return false;

    $scope.motivation.splice( $index , 1 );

    $http.post( 'api/admin/motivation/deleteMotivation/', {
        motivation : motivation
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Bład komunikacji z API' );
    });

};

$scope.createMotivation = function ( motivation ) {

    $http.post( 'api/admin/motivation/createMotivation/', {
        motivation : motivation
    } ).

    success( function( data ){
        $scope.msgMot = true;

        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.msgMot = false;
            $scope.motivationForm = false;
            $scope.motivation = {};
        }, 1500);
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Bład komunikacji z API' );
    });

};

$http.get( 'api/admin/motivation/getMotivation' ).
success( function( data ){
    $scope.motivation = data;
}).error( function(){
    console.log( 'Bład komunikacji z API' );
});

}]);
```

And i find out that 'motivation' return all objects when i need in saveChangesMotivation() and deleteMotivation one specific object. I used this functions in others controllers but not together and they works fine. How can i resolve this?

EDIT:
View

```
<div ng-click="motivationForm = true; boredForm = false; goalsForm = false" ng-show="!motivationForm">Add</div>
        <div ng-click="motivationForm = false" ng-show="motivationForm">Hide</div>
        <div ng-show="!showAllMot" ng-click="showAllMot = true">Show</div>
        <div ng-show="showAllMot" ng-click="showAllMot = false">Hide</div>
        <div ng-show="motivationForm">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <form ng-submit="createMotivation( motivation )">

                    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" class="form-control inline" placeholder="Dodaj tekst motywacyjny" ng-model="motivation.text"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <button type="submit" ng-show="!msgMot">Sobmit</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right inline" ng-show="msgMot" disabled>Saved</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div ng-show="showAllMot">
            <div ng-repeat="m in motivation">
                <form ng-submit="saveChangesMotivation( motivation )">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <div ng-show="!editMot">{{m.text}}</div>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="m.text" ng-show="editMot" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">

                            <button ng-show="!editMot" ng-click="editMot = true">Edit</button>
                            <button type="submit" ng-show="editMot" ng-click="editMot = false">Save</button>
                            <button ng-click="deleteMotivation( motivation , $index )">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

When i used for example createMotivation function and checked it in my console in network that function than shows me error that i dont set anything,probably becouse 'motivation' returns all objects instead one specific. I know that returns all object becouse in this function used console.log( $scope.motivation ) and saw this in console. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please explain problem in more detail, it is hard to understand what your issue is. Also show where you pass arguments in from your html

Comment: Check out me Edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the entire collection to each function during your ng-repeat:

```
<form ng-submit="saveChangesMotivation( motivation )">
```

For each of your function calls, change "motivation" to "m" which is the variable you used to define the repeater (ng-repeat="m in motivator")

```
<form ng-submit="saveChangesMotivation( m )">
```

and so on for the other functions. Then you'll have the specific object in each function instead of the whole collection.

Comment: Almost great, saveChangesMotivation() and deleteMotivation() works but createMotivation() not :(

Comment: It's actually the same problem. You shouldn't need to pass anything at all to your create function. Build the new object to add in the function (or extend it from a default), add it to your $scope.motivator **collection**, and send the collection to the server. Likewise for the delete function, just pass the index and splice it from your $scope.motivation **collection**, which then gets passed to the server to save. A lot of these issues are more apparent if you structure your angular app using services, etc as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Did that work? I think my original answer is the correct one for the issue and may help others.

Answer (score 0):

I think that works in that way beacuse you must use different methods depending what you want to do. If you want obtain data use method GET `$http.get()`, if you want submit data use method POST `$http.post()`, and so on.

- GET (`$http.get`)
- HEAD (`$http.head`)
- POST (`$http.post`)
- DELETE (`$http.delete`)
- PUT (`$http.put`)
- JSONP (`$http.jsonp`)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what your problem is, I'd like to point out that as a rule, having server requests in you controller is a bad idea. It would be better to place them in a service or factory, and call them when needed. This would make your code more re-usable and easier to test.

```
app.factory('MyDataFactory', ['$http',
  function($http){
    motivationFactory = {};
     var create = function() {
        $http.post(); // Your post() code here
    }

    var read = function() {
        $http.get();  // Your get() code here
    }

    var update  = function() {
        $http.put();  // Your put() code here
    }

    var delete = function() {
        $http.delete();  // Your delete() code here
    }

    motivationFactory.create = create;
    motivationFactory.read= read;
    motivationFactory.update= update;
    motivationFactory.create = delete;

    return motivationFactory;
  }]);
```

The `$http` service runs asynchronously returns a promise. You can now call the service from the controller like this.

```
app.controller('MotivationController', function($scope, MyDataFactory) {
  MyDataFactory.read().then(function successCallback(response){
    // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
    $scope.motivation = response;
  }, function errorCallback(response){
   // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log(response);
});
```

Note that the above code has not been implemented, but should give you an outline.

Comment: Have to try with that.